# leetcode 14. Longest Common Prefix Javascript

Tags: javascript

[leetcode problem 14][1]
Not understanding why the output is rejected for Longest Common Prefix. Not pasting in the code submission as the problem is my misreading the question.

```
Wrong Answer

Details 

Input

["reflower","flow","flight"]

Output

"fl"

Expected

""
```

Description copied from site :

Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.

If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".

Example 1:

```
Input: strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
Output: "fl"
```

Example 2:

```
Input: strs = ["dog","racecar","car"]
Output: ""
```

Explanation: There is no common prefix among the input strings.

Constraints:

```
0 <= strs.length <= 200
0 <= strs[i].length <= 200
strs[i] consists of only lower-case English letters.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the failing test case, the output "fl" is rejected because one of the strings does not start with "fl".

The misunderstanding concerning the meaning of *common prefix* may be in one of those two terms:

- **prefix**: the substring must occur *at the start* of the string -- before ("pre") all other characters, not at the end of a string (a "suffix") or anywhere else (a "substring"). In your failing test case, the third word has "fl", but that "fl" does not occur at the start of the string, so it is irrelevant.
- **common**: *all* input strings must have that prefix, not just a few. In the failing test case, there are two words that start with "flow", but since the third word does not have it, it does not count as *common*.

Comment: That was it thank you! I misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As the problem goes:

> ... find the longest common prefix string...

You need to find the longest common **prefix** - which is the string at the beginning of each word.

In your case, the input is `["reflower","flow","flight"]`.

While `flow` and `flight` have the same prefix - `fl`, `reflower` doesn't have the same prefix (since it does not start with `fl` but with `re`), and as a result the whole 3 words doesn't have a common prefix so the output should be `""`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
  // const strs = ["flower","flow","flight"];
  // console.log(strs);

  if (!strs.length) return "";

  for (let i = 0; i <= strs[0]; i++) {
    if (!strs.every((string) => string[i] === strs[0][i])) {
      return strs[0].slice(0, i);
    }
  }
  
  return strs[0].slice();
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please feel free to review [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for any support / guidance with answering questions.